# L'Hospital's rule, alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There's an easy way to prove a simpler version of L'Hospital's rule: If $f(b)=g(b)=0$ and $g'(b) \neq 0$ then (f and g are once differentiable real functions)

$$\lim_{x \to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to b} \frac{f(b) + f'(b)(x-b) + \varphi(x-b)}{g(b) + g'(b)(x-b) + \psi(x-b)}$$

where $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\varphi(x)}{x}=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\psi(x)}{x}=0$, so expanding the above fraction by $1/(x-b)$ and using $f(b)=g(b)=0$ we get

$$\lim_{x \to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to b} \frac{f'(b) + \frac{\varphi(x-b)}{x-b}}{g'(b)+\frac{\psi(x-b)}{x-b}}= \frac{f'(b)}{g'(b)}.$$

Unfortunately this proof needs $g'(b) \neq 0$, whereas L'Hospital's rule only needs that $\lim_{x \to b} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists. Does anyone see how to remedy the above proof to prove real L'Hospital? This proof would be so nice, because it pretty much only uses the definition (or a possible definition) of the differential.

Comment: How did you get $f'(b), g'(b) $ replaced by $f'(x), g'(x) $? The result you state and prove is simply an immediate consequence of definition of derivative and is not really comparable to the more powerful LHospital Rule.

Comment: You might want to just calculate $\lim g/f$ instead...?

Comment: oops, now it should be correct, sorry. But I think the result does have some merit, it's immediate from the definition, but it's not obvious.

Comment: You should also state the hypotheses clearly. Where are $f,g$ differentiable etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that proof simpler:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{(f(x)-f(b))/(x-b)}{(g(x)-g(b))/(x-b)} \to \frac{f'(b)}{g'(b)}.$$